# Confused with OAuth 2.0 in flutter

Tags: flutter, oauth-2.0, rest, square

I am trying to develop a Flutter app, with which users can login with their Square account credentials, and I can use OAuth2.0 to get their access token, and use it to make calls to the Square API.

I am confused with the whole flow: after the users sign in with their Square credentials, how do I get their client secret/ app id (which are required for the obtaintoken API call). To get the access token I need those, but there doesn't seem to be any functionality for that. Right now I am testing by hardcoding both in a .env file, but how to do it for an end user? I'm currently using FlutterAppAuth.

Answer (score 1):

You would use *your* client secret and application id. The idea behind OAuth API in Square is that the Square merchant(s) you onboard do not need to worry about creating an application, so they actually wouldn't have these credentials at all.

Using the OAuth API, you will be able to generate an access token using `ObtainToken` with the code that you receive. The rest of the parameters are specific to your application.

You can see the full flow on the doc site here: https://developer.squareup.com/docs/oauth-api/how-oauth-works.